# Extract word containing "@" from a string in r

Tags: r

I have a data as follows:

```
emails
my email id: xxx.x@gmail.com
email to: bb_b@yahool.com
mailto: hj-hk@grk.co
you can send email to ghhd@test.co
gggh@gh.tom
```

I only want to extract the word containing "@" as follows:

```
email
xxxx@gmail.com
bbb@yahool.com
hjhk@grk.co
ghhd@test.co
gggh@gh.tom
```

Till now I was doing it manually for each row using

```
substring(data[1,1], 14)
```

But clearly this is the worst thing one can do when data size is as large as 900k. Any help will be highly appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `regexpr`.

```
regmatches(d$emails, regexpr("(\\S*\\@\\S+\\.\\S*)", d$emails))
# [1] "xxxx@gmail.com" "bbb@yahool.com" "hjhk@grk.co"    "ghhd@test.co"  
# [5] "gggh@gh.tom"
```

***Data***

```
d <- structure(list(emails = c("my email id: xxxx@gmail.com", "email to: bbb@yahool.com", 
"mailto: hjhk@grk.co", "you can send email to ghhd@test.co", 
"gggh@gh.tom")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I just found that your code is not working if the email is having any special characters like . or _ or -. Can you please help me. I have modified my question with emails containing special characters

Comment: @user3642360 See update.